# Universal Analytics session increase

Tags: google-analytics

We implemented the new Universal Analytics tracking code on wednesday and since then have seen a dramatic increase in the number of sessions reported. We have not changed the session timeout settings as these should not be affected. This property is an advertising network where each iframe has the analytics embedded. Average session duration has drastically decreased from 10minutes to under 3 minutes as if each user is generating a new session on every iframe load rather than the actual browser session.

[image]

Is there any setting that we missed that can correct this or is switching back to the old embed code the only option?

Comment: There is not enough info (which iframe loads ?) to answer that question, but switching back seems a bad idea (it's UA under the hood in any case, and since the old code will eventually be retired and does not support all features you should rather find the problem then evading it). First thing check if your own domain name is in the referral exclusion settings, then check with the Ga debugger if the client id changes between visits - more and shorter sessions sounds like the sessions are interrupted and that's most often due to a wrong cookie domain.

Comment: Clarification: there are hundreds of iframes served from example.app on being loaded on thousands of websites publisher1.app publisher2.app etc. Excluding each publisher as a referral is not feasible due to the sheer volume or publishers. Verified on 2 clients using different vpn's that the client id is constant for loads of different iframes on different publishers. Cookie domain appears to remain correct "example.app"